# Tower of powersets

Tags: coq, powerset

I would like to define a family of types `PowersetTower : Type -> nat -> Type` such that:

1. `PowersetTower A 0 = A`
2. `PowersetTower A (n+1) = Ensemble (PowersetTower A n)` (that is, `PowersetTower A n -> Prop`)

Is that possible? One idea would be something like

```
Inductive PowersetTower : Type -> nat -> Type :=
| base : forall (A : Type), PowersetTower A 0
| step : forall (A : Type) (n : nat), (PowersetTower A n -> Prop) -> PowersetTower A (S n)
.
```

but here Coq complains about the non-strictly-positive occurrence of `PowersetTower` in the constructor `step`. However, it is `PowersetTower A n` that occurs on the left-hand-side of the arrow, and not `PowersetTower A (S n)`, so why does Coq forbid this? It seems OK to me, because I am defining 'larger' types using 'smaller' ones. Would this definition cause a problem if accepted (perhaps using the `bypass_check(positivity)` attribute)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to define is not an inductive family indexed on `n`, but a type depending on `n`. You can do this by recursion:

```
Fixpoint PowersetTower (A : Type) (n : nat) : Type :=
  match n with
    | 0 => A
    | S n' => (PowersetTower A n') -> Prop
  end.
```

And this is a perfectly valid recursion on `n`, since it is always smaller in recursive calls – although the returned term happens to be a type, but this is all the salt of dependent types.